# Getting right currfile with own class loaded from subdirectory

Tags: currfile

When writing my own class in a subdirectory, e.g. `myclass/aclass.cls`, and I use the **currfile** package to load that class's current file path, it always returns the information of my main file only. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong or if it's not even possible to do?

Here is an example:

**TeX sample tree**

```
.
├── myclass
│   └── aclass.cls
├── test.pdf
└── test.tex
```

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass{myclass/aclass}

\begin{document}
\section{Class file: \aclassfile}
\end{document}
```

**myclass/aclass.cls**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{aclass}
\LoadClass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{currfile}
\edef\aclassfile{\currfilepath}
```

**test.pdf**

[image: test.pdf image output]

Comment: don't do `\documentclass{myclass/aclass}` do `\documentclass{aclass}` and arrange that that file is in your TEXINPUTS path. The argument to `docuemntclass` should be a _class name_ not a file path

Comment: Thx! Okay, I recognized that even if I put the `aclass.cls` into the main dir, it also doesn't resolve the right filepath.